# How do I transfer the relationships in PowerBI desktop to PowerBI Paginated Report Builder

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, reportbuilder, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have developed some visuals in PowerBI desktop and I want to produce the same visuals in PowerBI paginated reports using report builder.

I want to retain the relationships in my PowerBI desktop data model.

Is it possible, or do I need to use report builder to build the same relationships?

Answer (score 0):

If you publish the PBIX file to the service, you can connect to the dataset from the Paginated Report Builder. The dataset will include all relationships built in the desktop model. You can write DAX or MDX queries to retrieve the data you need.

Comment: unfortunately it is design flaw relationship are not working